# Google spreadsheet data in select box with "Chosen jQuery plugin"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-sheets

I am trying to add "Chosen jQuery plugin" in my select box. Here data coming from google spreadsheet.
I tried code below under my function to append list. but this not working.

```
Option = "<li class="active-result">" + this.gsx$list.$t + "</li>";
      $('ul.chosen-results').append(Option);
```

Here is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/hmdycnxh/)

```js
function createLIST(){ 

 // url to spreadsheet
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1a00YuGgCNuzYfw7C4qxvpdlbRRiDHV45gPWwQ7E6X0E/o11yyjo/public/values?alt=json";

 //var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/o11yyjo/public/values?alt=json";
 
 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
 
  var entry = data.feed.entry;
 //function(){$('ul.chzn-results').empty();},
  $(entry).each(function(){
    // add each option
   
   //Option = "<li class="active-result">" + this.gsx$list.$t + "</li>";
          //$('ul.chosen-results').append(Option);
   Option = "<option>" + this.gsx$list.$t + "</option>";
            $('#products-list').append(Option);
         
  });
  
 
 });
 
}
$(document).ready(function(e){

    // now add the GoogleSpread sheet list
    createLIST()
    //$('#products-list').chosen();
    
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist id='products'>
    
</datalist>

<select id='products-list'>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize chosen plugin only after options are added from the JSON response.

```js
function createLIST() {

  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1a00YuGgCNuzYfw7C4qxvpdlbRRiDHV45gPWwQ7E6X0E/o11yyjo/public/values?alt=json";

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var entry = data.feed.entry;
    $(entry).each(function() {
      Option = "<option>" + this.gsx$list.$t + "</option>";
      $('#products-list').append(Option);
    });

    // initialize chosen after options are added 
    $('#products-list').chosen();

  });
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  createLIST();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<datalist id='products'>

</datalist>

<select id='products-list'>
</select>
```